# Id and Property elements in hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate

From Hibernate Documentation :
The id element is the declaration of the identifier property. The name="id" mapping attribute declares the name of the JavaBean property and tells Hibernate to use the getId() and setId() methods to access the property. The column attribute tells Hibernate which column of the mapped table holds the primary key value.

The nested generator element specifies the identifier generation strategy (aka how are identifier values generated?).

We have,

```
 <id 

   name="id" column="Id_Column in Database">

   <generator class=""/>

 </id>
```

Why can't it be something like this?

```
 <property 

  name="id" column="Id_Column in Database">

  <generator class=""/>

 </property>
```

Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: i think your question doesn't uploaded successfully. What after line which says We Have, and Why can't it be somethink like this? statement of your question

Answer (score 4):

I think, the only difference can be a performance. Because in the second case Hibernate engine(XML Parser) will have to fetch every property tag to identify whether it is primary or not, while in first by having separate tag, it is easy to fetch the one tag, and it is more readable also.

Comment: By Gavin King itself : Hibernate makes the mapping type determination using reflection when the mapping files are processed. This can take time and resources, so if startup performance is important you should consider explicitly defining the type to use. Does it also conform to the above situation?

Comment: Yes,During start up second case declaration will take more time and resources than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare definitions of `<id>` and `<property>` tags using Hibernate mapping file **DTD(Document Type Definition**):

Definition of an `<id>` tag:

```
<!-- Declares the id type, column and generation algorithm for an entity class.
If a name attribut is given, the id is exposed to the application through the 
named property of the class. If not, the id is only exposed to the application 
via Session.getIdentifier() -->

<!ELEMENT id (meta*,column*,type?,generator?)>
    <!ATTLIST id name CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST id node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST id access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST id column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST id type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST id length CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST id unsaved-value CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

Definition of a `<property>` tag:

```
<!-- Property of an entity class or component, component-element, composite-id, etc. 
JavaBeans style properties are mapped to table columns. -->

<!ELEMENT property (meta*,(column|formula)*,type?)>
    <!ATTLIST property name CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST property node CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property access CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property type CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property column CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property length CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property precision CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property scale CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property not-null (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property unique (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST property unique-key CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property index CDATA #IMPLIED>                <!-- include the columns spanned by this property in an index -->
    <!ATTLIST property update (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property insert (true|false) #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property optimistic-lock (true|false) "true"> <!-- only supported for properties of a class (not component) -->
    <!ATTLIST property formula CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST property lazy (true|false) "false">
    <!ATTLIST property generated (never|insert|always) "never">
```

The line `<!ELEMENT id (meta*,column*,type?,generator?)>` explains that `<id>` tag can include `<generator>` tag, but tag `<property>` can't. Etc, etc, etc...